# Running Cronjob under cygwin

Tags: linux, unix, scheduled-tasks, cron

I have script which need to run using cygwin crontab.

So what i have done.

installed two additional cygwin packages using cygwin setup.exe

Cron and cygrunsrv

Then in installed the new crontab

```
* * * * * sh /housekeeper.sh -t CPS
```

since i could not get the output of the housekeeper.sh, i checked the status of

```
cronevents.exe
```

This gives me following error message.

```
2012/05/28 18:22:01 [SYSTEM] /usr/sbin/cron: PID 3880: (CRON) error (can't switc
h user context)
```

could anybody help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance for anyhelp

Answer (score 3):

This error appears in the Windows Application Event Log and occurs because the account running the service can't switch user context (see http://www.davidjnice.com/cygwin_cron_service.html)

Change the user who runs the service to the real user who has to run the script.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your cron treats the 6th word (sh) as a username under which to run the command. Try using

```
* * * * * yourusername /path/to/script.sh options
```

and make sure script.sh sets its `PATH` properly because cron might not set any `PATH` at all.

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple users, and you want to make this run then : 
There are three methods for switching the user context without password, 
   Method 1: Create a token from scratch
   Method 2: LSA authentication package
   Method 3: With password

I'm explaining here the Method 2.
Try command "cyglsa-config"
Also, make the Log On is set to Local System account.
and reboot the system.

[Image for LogOn option to be set for cron deamon service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czK36.jpg)
More details: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-nopasswd1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.